# Error while running Laravel-snappy html to pdf

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-snappy

I installed laravel-snappy using the official documentation but when i try to run my application i get this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure() in D:\php\myapp\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-snappy\src\LumenServiceProvider.php:21 Stack trace: #0 D:\php\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(574): Barryvdh\Snappy\LumenServiceProvider->register() #1 D:\php\myapp\bootstrap\app.php(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->register(Object(Barryvdh\Snappy\LumenServiceProvider)) #2 D:\php\myapp\public\index.php(36): require_once('D:\php\myapp\bo...') #3 D:\php\myapp\server.php(21): require_once('D:\php\myapp\pu...') #4 {main} thrown in D:\php\myapp\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-snappy\src\LumenServiceProvider.php on line 21

Another one : 
when i use anchor tag for routing a download like below

`<a href="{{ route('generate-pdf',['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>`

It goes to

`http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20route('generate-pdf',['download'=%3E'pdf'])%20%7D%7D`

why is it like that?

Why do i get this error and how do i resolve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.4

Comment: I shouldn't  add lumen commands into the bootstrap/app.php right? If i remove that its working. Is that the problem?